# VBA to insert Word document Filename and Path on separate lines, and Saved Date on another separate line

Tags: vba, ms-word, field

I know how to insert fields Filename and Path, and Saved Date using the Word ribbon.  I have also found how to insert them with VBA/Macro code.

However, how do I insert them with a Macro so they are dynamic fields that I can right-click and Update, like the fields that are inserted with the ribbon?
Due to long filenames and paths, I want them on separate lines.

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro while you do it? I would start there.

Comment: The path is not going to be a dynamic path without a LOT of coding. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Recording the macro works beautifully, including that the fields inserted will update when I right-click on them and choose Update.  Thanks very much!